# 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

Tags: c

I am attempting to run this code; compiles the code fine, with a few warnings, but when i try to run it it just crashes. This is the code that i am trying to run:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct maze_data{
    int* maze_array;
    int* start_location;
    int* end_location;
    int* rows;
    int* columns;
};

struct maze_data get_data(void);

void main(){

    struct maze_data data_object;

    data_object = get_data();

}

struct maze_data get_data(void) {
    char c;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int numberlength = 0;
    char number[2];
    int size_of_file;
    int number_of_numbers;
    char characters_in_file[100000]; 
    int numbers_in_file[100000];
    int space_locations[100000];
    char fname[100] = "";
    int rows;
    int columns;
    int mazenumbers[1000][1000];
    struct maze_data data_object;
    int start[2];
    int end[2];

    printf("enter file name: ");                
    gets(fname);

    FILE *fpoint;
    fopen_s(&fpoint, fname, "r+");              
    if (fpoint == NULL) {                       
        printf("No Such File !! ");
        return;
    }

    while (1) {
        c = fgetc(fpoint);                      
        if (feof(fpoint)) {
            printf("\n");
            size_of_file = i - 1;               
            break;
        }
        characters_in_file[i] = c;
        i++;
    }

    for (i = size_of_file; i >= 0; i--) {
        characters_in_file[i + 1] = characters_in_file[i];
    }
    characters_in_file[0] = ' ';

    for (i = 0; i < (size_of_file + 1); i++) {
        if (characters_in_file[i] == '\n'  || characters_in_file[i] == ' ') {
            space_locations[j] = i;
            j++;
        }
    }
    number_of_numbers = j - 1;

    for (i = 0; i < number_of_numbers; i++) {
        numberlength = (space_locations[i + 1] - 1) - (space_locations[i]);
        number[0] = characters_in_file[space_locations[i]+1];
        if (numberlength == 2) {
            number[1] = characters_in_file[space_locations[i + 1] - 1];
        }   
        else {
            number[1] = ' ';
        }
        if (numberlength > 0) {
            j = atoi(number);
            numbers_in_file[i] = j;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < number_of_numbers; i++) {
        if (numbers_in_file[i] < 0) {
            for (j = 0; j < number_of_numbers; j++) {
                numbers_in_file[j + i] = numbers_in_file[j + i + 1];
            }
            number_of_numbers--;
        }
    }

    rows = numbers_in_file[0];
    columns = numbers_in_file[1];
    start[0] = numbers_in_file[2];
    start[1] = numbers_in_file[3];
    end[0] = numbers_in_file[4];
    end[1] = numbers_in_file[5];

    k = 7;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            mazenumbers[i][j] = numbers_in_file[k];
            k++;
        }
    }

    data_object.maze_array = mazenumbers;
    data_object.start_location = start;
    data_object.end_location = end;
    data_object.rows = rows;
    data_object.columns = columns;

    return data_object;
}
```

I am getting these errors:

(38): warning C4013: 'gets' undefined; assuming extern returning int

(44): warning C4033: 'get_data' must return a value

(123): warning C4047: '=': 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from

'int(*)[1000]'

(126): warning C4047: '=': 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

(127): warning C4047: '=': 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

(131): warning C4715: 'get_data': not all control paths return a value

Can someone please explain what is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: `data_object.rows = rows;`. The left hand side is `int *`. The right hand side is `int`. Your compiler is warning you for a reason. Don't ignore it. What are you trying to do? BTW, you have other errors too.

Comment: For the gets() warning, depending on the compiler (such as recent versions of Visual Studio), it may have been removed from the library. Try using gets_s() or fgets(...,stdin) instead.

Comment: Quote: "compiles the code fine, with a few warnings" Don't ignore the warnings. Fix all warnings before even trying to run the program

Answer (score 0):

`get_data()` is defined to return `struct maze_data`, so it must always do that, even for error conditions :

```
if (fpoint == NULL) {
    printf("No Such File !! ");
    return;
}
```

Since this is checking for what is likely a fatal error, an easy way to fix it is to replace `return` with `exit(1);`

You define your struct to have pointers to integers :

```
struct maze_data {
    int* maze_array;
    int* start_location;
    int* end_location;
    int* rows;
    int* columns;
}
```

And then try to assign an array of arrays to one pointer:

```
int mazenumbers[1000][1000];

data_object.maze_array = mazenumbers;
```

And integer values to other pointers:

```
int rows;
int columns;

data_object.rows = rows;
data_object.columns = columns;
```

For rows and columns, it looks like you should just change the struct definition to

```
int rows;
int columns;
```

For `maze_array`, it depends exactly what you are trying to return...is it the entire `mazenumbers` array of arrays, or just a certain row?  Either way, you cannot statically allocate the memory for `mazenumbers` if a pointer to the memory is going to be returned, you will need to use `malloc()` to allocate heap memory for it.